# My Rust code is much longer than the equivalent Python one, with the wrong result

Tags: rust

When converting [existing Python code](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/) to Rust, the number of lines increased, with many type changes, and worst of all with the wrong result! I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a way to optimize it:

The main function is:

```
fn main() {
    let series = [
        30, 21, 29, 31, 40, 48, 53, 47, 37, 39, 31, 29, 17, 9, 20, 24, 27, 35, 41, 38, 27, 31, 27,
        26, 21, 13, 21, 18, 33, 35, 40, 36, 22, 24, 21, 20, 17, 14, 17, 19, 26, 29, 40, 31, 20, 24,
        18, 26, 17, 9, 17, 21, 28, 32, 46, 33, 23, 28, 22, 27, 18, 8, 17, 21, 31, 34, 44, 38, 31,
        30, 26, 32,
    ];

    triple_exponential_smoothing(&series, 12, 0.716, 0.029, 0.993, 24);
}
```

`triple_exponential_smoothing` calls two other functions, which I tested, and they give correct results:

```
fn initial_trend(series: &[i32], slen: i32) -> f32 {
    let mut sum = 0.0;
    for i in 0..slen as usize { // in Python: for i in range(slen)
        sum += (series[i + slen as usize] as f32 - series[i] as f32) / slen as f32;
    }
    return sum / slen as f32;
}
```

Which is a conversion of the Python code:

```py
def initial_trend(series, slen):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(slen):
        sum += float(series[i+slen] - series[i]) / slen
    return sum / slen

# >>> initial_trend(series, 12)
# -0.7847222222222222
```

The second one is:

```
fn initial_seasonal_components(series: &[i32], slen: i32) -> Vec<f32> {
    let mut seasonals = Vec::new();
    let n_seasons = series.len() as i32 / slen;
    // # compute season averages
    let season_chunks = series //season_averages
            .chunks(slen as usize)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let season_averages = season_chunks
        .iter()
        .map(|chunk| chunk.iter().sum::<i32>() as f32 / chunk.len() as f32)
        .collect::<Vec<f32>>();
    // # compute initial values
    for i in 0..slen as usize {
        let mut sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0;
        for j in 0..n_seasons as usize {
            sum_of_vals_over_avg +=
                series[i + j * slen as usize] as f32 - season_averages[j] as f32;
        }
        seasonals.push(sum_of_vals_over_avg / n_seasons as f32);
    }
    return seasonals;
}
```

Which is a conversion of the Python code:

```py
def initial_seasonal_components(series, slen):
    seasonals = {}
    season_averages = []
    n_seasons = int(len(series)/slen)
    # compute season averages
    for j in range(n_seasons):
        season_averages.append(sum(series[slen*j:slen*j+slen])/float(slen))
    # compute initial values
    for i in range(slen):
        sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0
        for j in range(n_seasons):
            sum_of_vals_over_avg += series[slen*j+i]-season_averages[j]
        seasonals[i] = sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons
    return seasonals

# >>> initial_seasonal_components(series, 12)
# {0: -7.4305555555555545, 1: -15.097222222222221, 2: -7.263888888888888, 3: -5.097222222222222, 4: 3.402777777777778, 5: 8.069444444444445, 6: 16.569444444444446, 7: 9.736111111111112, 8: -0.7638888888888887, 9: 1.902777777777778, 10: -3.263888888888889, 11: -0.7638888888888887}
```

The error looks to be in this function:

```
fn triple_exponential_smoothing(
    series: &[i32],
    slen: i32,
    alpha: f32,
    beta: f32,
    gamma: f32,
    n_preds: i32,
) {
    let mut result: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    let mut seasonals = initial_seasonal_components(&series, slen);
    println!("The seasonalities are: {:#?}", seasonals);
    let mut smooth = 0.0;
    let mut trend = 0.0;
    // for i in range(len(series)+n_preds):
    for i in 0..(series.len() + n_preds as usize) as usize {
        match i {
            0 => {
                // # initial values
                smooth = series[0] as f32;
                trend = initial_trend(&series, slen);
                println!("The initial_trend is: {:#?}", trend);
                result.push(series[0] as f32);
            }
            i if i >= series.len() => {
                // # we are forecasting
                let m = i - series.len() + 1;
                result.push(
                    (smooth as usize + m * trend as usize) as f32 + seasonals[i % slen as usize],
                )
            }
            _ => {
                let val = series[i];
                let last_smooth = smooth;
                smooth = alpha * (val as f32 - seasonals[i % slen as usize])
                    + (1.0 - alpha) * (smooth + trend);
                trend = beta * (smooth - last_smooth) + (1.0 - beta) * trend;
                seasonals[i % slen as usize] = gamma * (val as f32 - smooth)
                    + (1 - gamma as usize) as f32 * seasonals[i % slen as usize];
                result.push(smooth + trend + seasonals[i % slen as usize]);
            }
        }
    }
    println!("The forecast is: {:#?}", result);
}
```

Which is a conversion of the Python code:

```py
def triple_exponential_smoothing(series, slen, alpha, beta, gamma, n_preds):
    result = []
    seasonals = initial_seasonal_components(series, slen)
    for i in range(len(series)+n_preds):
        if i == 0: # initial values
            smooth = series[0]
            trend = initial_trend(series, slen)
            result.append(series[0])
            continue
        if i >= len(series): # we are forecasting
            m = i - len(series) + 1
            result.append((smooth + m*trend) + seasonals[i%slen])
        else:
            val = series[i]
            last_smooth, smooth = smooth, alpha*(val-seasonals[i%slen]) + (1-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
            trend = beta * (smooth-last_smooth) + (1-beta)*trend
            seasonals[i%slen] = gamma*(val-smooth) + (1-gamma)*seasonals[i%slen]
            result.append(smooth+trend+seasonals[i%slen])
    return result

# # forecast 24 points (i.e. two seasons)
# >>> triple_exponential_smoothing(series, 12, 0.716, 0.029, 0.993, 24)
# [30, 20.34449316666667, 28.410051892109554, 30.438122252647577, 39.466817731253066, ...
```

[My complete code is available in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=06a86d4fb8cf2ef99e665d168f3cea05&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

I appreciate any comment to optimize the code and fix the error.

Comment: Consider the minimal aspect of [mcve].... there's a TON of code here....

Comment: be more careful when you cast thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rust, you are converting everything to `usize` all the time:

```
(1 - gamma as usize) as f32
```

If you think about that one, `(1 - gamma as usize)` can only ever be `0` or `1` depending on the value of `gamma`. If you instead change it to

```
(1.0 - gamma) as f32
```

And also change

```
(smooth as usize + m * trend as usize) as f32
```

to

```
(smooth + m as f32 * trend)
```

Then you get the same result as in Python.

As for performance, this looks about right, but you could introduce some temporary variables to avoid recomputing the same things all the time (although the optimizer should help). The default compilation mode for Rust is debug, be sure to switch to release for benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting here the best comments and answer I received, hope be useful for others:

try to minimize (and possibly to reduce to zero) the number of “as” casts in your code. into()/from() and try_from() help;

Try to replace some raw loops with iterators;

The triple_exponential_smoothing function has some arguments that are easy to confuse at the calling point because Rust currently doesn’t have named arguments. To avoid the problem you could try to pack some arguments in structs/tuples.

Using “return” at the end of Rust functions isn’t much idiomatic.

Also, something worth noting is that in Python, the floating point type is double floating point, which would be f64 in Rust. This likely would introduce small differences in accuracy, although likely nothing major.

The functional neat code the replaced mine is in this [PlayGound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0bd893bdb65f93655a4ee93a05bc7c51&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
fn main() {
    let series = [
        30,21,29,31,40,48,53,47,37,39,31,29,17,9,20,24,27,35,41,38,
        27,31,27,26,21,13,21,18,33,35,40,36,22,24,21,20,17,14,17,19,
        26,29,40,31,20,24,18,26,17,9,17,21,28,32,46,33,23,28,22,27,
        18,8,17,21,31,34,44,38,31,30,26,32];

    triple_exponential_smoothing(&series, 12, 0.716, 0.029, 0.993, 24);
}

fn initial_trend(series: &[i32], slen: usize) -> f32 {
    series[..slen].iter().zip(&series[slen..])
        .map(|(&a, &b)| (b as f32 - a as f32) / slen as f32).sum::<f32>() / slen as f32
}

fn initial_seasonal_components (series: &[i32], slen: usize) -> Vec<f32> {
    let n_seasons = series.len() / slen;
    // # compute season averages
    let season_averages = series //season_averages
        .chunks(slen)
        .map(|chunk| chunk.iter().sum::<i32>() as f32 / chunk.len() as f32)
        .collect::<Vec<f32>>();
    // # compute initial values
    (0..slen).map(|i| {
        let mut sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0;
        for j in 0..n_seasons {
            sum_of_vals_over_avg += series[i + j * slen] as f32 - season_averages[j] as f32;
        }
        sum_of_vals_over_avg / n_seasons as f32
    }).collect()
}

fn triple_exponential_smoothing(series: &[i32], slen: usize, alpha: f32, beta: f32,
                                gamma: f32, n_preds: usize) {
    let mut result: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    let mut seasonals = initial_seasonal_components(&series, slen);
    println!("The seasonalities are: {:#?}", seasonals);
    let mut smooth = 0.0;
    let mut trend = 0.0;

    for i in 0..(series.len() + n_preds) {
        match i {
            0 => {  // # initial values
                smooth = series[0] as f32;
                trend = initial_trend(&series, slen);
                println!("The initial_trend is: {:#?}", trend);
                result.push(series[0] as f32);
            },
            i if i >= series.len() => {  // # we are forecasting
                let m = i - series.len() + 1;
                result.push((smooth + m as f32 * trend) + seasonals[i % slen])
            },
            _ => {
                let val = series[i];
                let last_smooth = smooth;
                smooth = alpha * (val as f32 - seasonals[i % slen]) +
                    (1.0 - alpha)*(smooth + trend);
                trend = beta * (smooth - last_smooth) + (1.0 - beta) * trend;
                seasonals[i % slen] = gamma * (val as f32 - smooth) +
                    (1.0 - gamma) * seasonals[i % slen];
                result.push(smooth + trend + seasonals[i % slen]);
            }
        }
    }
    println!("The forecast is: {:#?}", result);
}
```